# WP toolbar only showing on frontend for some admins

Tags: wordpress, toolbar

We have several admins who all have the "Show toolbar when viewing site" option checked in their user profile but only some of them are actually able to see the toolbar. Others have the option checked but the toolbar doesn't show up. Additionally, we have a multisite setup and they are able to see the toolbar on one of the sites but not the other site.
After a bit of research, I've checked that  is included in our footer.php file and I tried deactivating a plugin called "Members" that wasn't activated on the site where they can see the toolbar, however, nothing seemed to change. While I thought it could be another plugin issue, what doesn't make sense is that it's not an issue for all admins, just a few.
Is there anything else that I should be checking?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes instead of checking if a user "is_admin()" plugins or functions will check which permissions users have to determine what features they can or cannot see. I might check to see if the users in question have different permissions despite being admins. Perhaps create some new admin users to test if it is an issue with user IDs after a certain number.

Consider turning on debugging to see if any errors prevent the bar from displaying. Also try the [query monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin. Check for errors and query issues with and without the suspected conflicting plugin activated.